# Help with MySQL Join

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have two tables, Sales (ISBN, Sale_Time, [Sale Data Fields]) and Affiliate_Sales (ISBN, Affiliate_Sale-Time, [Affiliate Data Fields]).

I'd like to query all the unexpired Sales (< 24 hours old) and unexpired Affiliate_Sales (< 72 hrs old) for a given set of ISBNs. I'd like a row to return for a given ISBN even if there are unexpired Sales but no unexpired Affiliate_Sales, AND vice-versa (but nothing should be returned when neither are there). I believe this is referred to as a FULL JOIN.

I don't think a UNION would work here because the tables differ on all fields except ISBN.

An answer to this question would be a query that does the proper join and checks for expiration in both tables.

Update: As you can see from my comments below, I'm trying to get all the Sales data and all the Affiliate_Sales data, Not just ISBN's and times.

Update 2: Here is what a result would look like

```
ISBN    Sale_DateTime   [Sale Fields…]  Affiliate_Sale_DateTime [Affiliate Sale Fields…]
1   11/6/2010 11:28    All the sale Fields  11/6/2010 0:28     All the affiliate Sale fields
2   NULL               NULLs                11/6/2010 0:28     All the affiliate Sale fields
3   11/6/2010 11:28    All the sale Fields  NULL               NULLs
```

If getting this requires more processing on the SQL side than just doing two basic SELECT queries as Bruno's long query suggests, maybe I should just do two?

Comment: Will you ever have ISBNs that are in the Affiliate_Sales table and not in Sales?

Comment: Then you would be able to use the where clauses I included in the union select posted earlier.

Comment: @babonk: While a full outer join may be what you need, MySQL does not support full outer joins - workarounds for this normally use UNION.

Comment: Please tell us about primary keys to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Defining requirements**

There is some contradicting and under-defined requirements that you specified in the question and comments, but I guess that is one of the reasons you are asking it.

Let me list them for you

1. you want to list ISBNs that are elements of either of two certain subsets from two tables (unexpired sales and unexpired affiliate sales)
2. you would like to show additional columns from both tables, not only ISBNs
3. you don't want NULLs

(I am using term subset because on the conceptual level it is not important to specify the conditions for your unexpired subsets)

Here are a couple of implications

- if you want to list ISBNs + fields from both tables for an entry that is only in one of the subsets then you *must* have NULLs for the other side; this contradicts #3
- is ISBN unique in both tables? If yes ignore this point: if ISBN is not unique then you need to specify how to join the subsets of two tables, otherwise you get each row from one for each for from another

**If ISBNs are unique**

Now, if your ISBNs are unique in both tables then Bruno's answer seems to point in the right direction (did not fully go through his SQL though, it does seem to be a bit overly complicated).

Ways to realize OUTER JOINS in mysql are

- UNION of LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN (not UNION ALL, but UNION, which will take distinct rows; it also matches the formal definition)
- UNION ALL of LEFT JOIN and RIGHT EXCLUSION JOIN (UNION ALL might be significantly faster, especially on big resultsets); this option has directly symmetrical equivalent of (UNION ALL of RIGHT JOIN and LEFT EXCLUSION JOIN)
- UNION ALL of INNER JOIN and LEFT EXCLUSION JOIN and RIGHT EXCLUSION JOIN (INNER JOIN might be significantly faster then LEFT JOIN if selectivity is high *and* if exclusion joins can use indexes)

If some of the terms used here are not clear see examples at [Common MySQL Queries](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1271#690).

**If ISBNs are not unique**

You need to define how to join, joining only on ISBNs will return Cartesian product of subsets (which, with additional fields will most certainly not be what you need in any scenario).

**EDIT**
After clarifications you can try this solution

```
SELECT * FROM Sales a LEFT JOIN Affiliate_Sales b ON a.ISBN=b.ISBN
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, Sale_DateTime, Now()) < 24 
      AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, Affiliate_Sale_DateTime, Now()) < 72 
      OR Affiliate_Sale_DateTime IS NULL)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Sales a RIGHT JOIN Affiliate_Sales b ON a.ISBN=b.ISBN
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, Affiliate_Sale_DateTime, Now()) < 72 
      AND Sale_DateTime IS NULL;
```

If you want it shorter you'll need to create views. Also, do take a look at the link provided, it is quite good.

Comment: Allow me to clarify: #3 is not true.  I do want NULL's.  You're probably misreading my comment below, where I was simply telling them that I didn't want "placeholder" fields that were always NULL so that a UNION could work.
Also, ISBN is the primary key of both of these tables.

Comment: @babonk, Ok if #3 is out of the picture and ISBN's are primary keys then the middle part of the answer gives you three ways to get FULL OUTER JOIN in mysql. Do you need help with translating concepts such as UNION of LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN into SQL?

Comment: The first one gets both only when Sale isn't expired, and there are unexpired affiliate sales or no affiliate sales

The second one gets it when there are no sales, and there are unexpired affiliates

what about when there are expired sales or affiliate sales?  in that case I'd like to still get the row if one of the two is unexpired

Comment: Got it by modifying the WHERE clauses on your query.  Thanks for the effort you put in, awarding you bounty

Comment: @babonk, glad you sorted it out. Do test the other variants for performance (and practice :)).

Comment: @babonk, what exactly is the query you ended with? With this query you will have to do extra work to extract each row ISBN. Plus, what happens when fields are named the same in sales and affiliate_sales tables? To distinguish them you will have to rely on their order in the resultset, which is not very robust since a simple change in the query (switch sales and affiliate_sales in the join clause for ex.) can lead to very different results without even being noticed in your code.

Comment: @Bruno, what do you mean with 'do extra work to extract each row ISBN'? As for the explicitly selecting the fields, yes, I agree that is a good practice (but not all the fields were given in the requirements therefore the `*`).

Comment: @Unreason, well you get two `ISBN` fields in the resultset, one for the sales table and another for the affiliate_sales table. Sometimes the first is NULL, sometimes the second is NULL, so to know what is the `ISBN` for each row, you will have to encapsulate the query with something like `SELECT COALESCE(a.ISBN,b.ISBN) ISBN FROM (...) t`, or put extra code in your DAO to check wether it should use the first or the second `ISBN` resultset field.

Comment: @Bruno, fair half point :D. For me it falls under the same category of good practice to actually list column names (and as you point out simple COALESCE will deal with it *if* you want to mangle the fields together; which *might not* be what OP wants).

Answer (score 0):

UNION should work if you use "AS" to define the name of the fields being returned so that they match up. For example:

```
SELECT ISBN, Sale_Time FROM Sales
UNION ALL
SELECT ISBN, Affiliate_Sale_Time AS Sale_Time FROM Affiliate_Sales
```

Comment: I don't just want to select ISBN and Sale_Time.  I want all the Sales data and all the Affiliate_Sales data for the given ISBN

Comment: UNION does not require the same column names, only the same number and types

Answer (score 0):

If you will always have an ISBN in the Sales table, then you can FULL JOIN and get the results you're looking for.  Otherwise, you would need to left join.

```
select *
from Sales s
FULL OUTER JOIN Affiliate_Sales asa on asa.ISBN = s.ISBN
where DATEDIFF(hh, s.Sale_Time, GETDATE()) < 24
OR DATEDIFF(hh, asa.Sale_Time, GETDATE()) < 72
```

EDIT - Try the above, or the following:

```
SELECT ISBN, Sale_Time 
FROM Sales s 
where DATEDIFF(hh, s.Sale_Time, GETDATE()) < 24
UNION ALL
SELECT ISBN, Affiliate_Sale_Time AS Sale_Time 
FROM Affiliate_Sales asa 
where DATEDIFF(hh, asa.Sale_Time, GETDATE()) < 72
```

If you want more fields, then you will have to name them specifically unless the tables are structured the same.  The FULL JOIN will give you all results.  My previous answer included an INNER JOIN which would have limited your results.

EDIT - Example on selecting fields that aren't matching:

```
select itemid, null, path, null, name
from Catalog

union all

select itemid, dsid, null, username, null
from DataSource
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that there will be Sales OR Affiliate_Sales.  So LEFT JOIN would seem to rely on one of them also

Comment: Could I SELECT fields that don't match between Sales and Affiliate_Sales without breaking the union?  I want those fields (named as they are)

Comment: You can stick NULLS in one select statement to open spots for your other fields.  I edited the answer to include an example from ReportServer database.

Comment: I don't want NULL's in my response though.  I just want the fields

Comment: As @Unreason noted, if you want fields that are in one table and not another, than you will need to accommodate for that with NULLs as placeholders.  If you have similar fields that you want in the same column as the same name, then you can stack those provided the datatype matches.  Can you provide the final list of fields from both tables and I'll plug them into a table without NULLs?

Answer (score 0):

You have indeed a `FULL OUTER JOIN` problem, but unfortunately this is currently not supported  by MySQL.

Luckily for us, we can emulate a `FULL OUTER JOIN` between tables A and B with:

- a LEFT OUTER JOIN from table A to table B to catch rows in A that are not in B AND row matches between A and B
- a RIGHT EXCLUSION JOIN from table B to table A to catch rows in B that are not in A

Since your tables differ on all fields except ISBN, we need to do it in two steps:

1. First we need to extract the ISBNs that match the expiration time criteria
2. Then we can retrieve the information from both tables for the previously selected ISBNs

Here is an example script to check our query:

```
CREATE TABLE sales ( 
   isbn INT NOT NULL
  ,sale_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
  ,sale_value VARCHAR(100)
  ,PRIMARY KEY (isbn)
);
CREATE TABLE affiliate_sales ( 
   isbn INT NOT NULL
  ,sale_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
  ,affiliate_sale_value VARCHAR(100)
  ,PRIMARY KEY (isbn)
);

INSERT INTO sales (isbn,sale_time,sale_value) VALUES (1,TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,-30,NOW()),'expired_sale');
INSERT INTO sales (isbn,sale_time,sale_value) VALUES (2,TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,-34,NOW()),'expired_sale');
INSERT INTO sales (isbn,sale_time,sale_value) VALUES (3,TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,-23,NOW()),'unexpired_sale');
INSERT INTO sales (isbn,sale_time,sale_value) VALUES (4,TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,-12,NOW()),'unexpired_sale');
INSERT INTO sales (isbn,sale_time,sale_value) VALUES (5,TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,-12,NOW()),'unexpired_sale_only');

INSERT INTO affiliate_sales (isbn,sale_time,affiliate_sale_value) VALUES (1,TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,-74,NOW()),'expired_affiliate_sale');
INSERT INTO affiliate_sales (isbn,sale_time,affiliate_sale_value) VALUES (2,TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,-54,NOW()),'unexpired_affiliate_sale');
INSERT INTO affiliate_sales (isbn,sale_time,affiliate_sale_value) VALUES (3,TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,-80,NOW()),'expired_affiliate_sale');
INSERT INTO affiliate_sales (isbn,sale_time,affiliate_sale_value) VALUES (4,TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,-12,NOW()),'unexpired_affiliate_sale');
INSERT INTO affiliate_sales (isbn,sale_time,affiliate_sale_value) VALUES (6,TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,-44,NOW()),'unexpired_affiliate_sale_only');
```

And here is the query that extract the data you need (sorry for the bad formatting, I couldn't find how to display it correctly inside pre block):

`SELECT unexpired_sal.isbn`
`, sal.sale_time, sal.sale_value`
`, afs.sale_time affiliate_sale_time, afs.affiliate_sale_value`
`FROM (`
`SELECT sal.isbn`
`FROM (`
`SELECT isbn FROM sales`
`WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,sale_time,NOW()) < 24`
`) sal`
`LEFT JOIN (`
`SELECT isbn FROM affiliate_sales`
`WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,sale_time,NOW()) < 72`
`) afs`
`ON afs.isbn = sal.isbn`
`UNION ALL`
`SELECT afs.isbn`
`FROM (`
`SELECT isbn FROM sales`
`WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,sale_time,NOW()) < 24`
`) sal`
`RIGHT JOIN (`
`SELECT isbn FROM affiliate_sales`
`WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,sale_time,NOW()) < 72`
`) afs`
`ON afs.isbn = sal.isbn`
`WHERE sal.isbn IS NULL`
`) unexpired_sal`
`LEFT JOIN (`
`SELECT * FROM sales`
`WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,sale_time,NOW()) < 24`
`) sal`
`ON sal.isbn = unexpired_sal.isbn`
`LEFT JOIN (`
`SELECT * FROM affiliate_sales`
`WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,sale_time,NOW()) < 72`
`) afs`
`ON afs.isbn = unexpired_sal.isbn`
`;`

You get the following output:

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| isbn | sale_time           | sale_value          | affiliate_sale_time | affiliate_sale_value          |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------+
|    3 | 2010-11-06 11:28:08 | unexpired_sale      |                NULL | NULL                          |
|    4 | 2010-11-06 22:28:08 | unexpired_sale      | 2010-11-06 22:28:08 | unexpired_affiliate_sale      |
|    5 | 2010-11-06 22:28:08 | unexpired_sale_only |                NULL | NULL                          |
|    2 |                NULL | NULL                | 2010-11-05 04:28:08 | unexpired_affiliate_sale      |
|    6 |                NULL | NULL                | 2010-11-05 14:28:08 | unexpired_affiliate_sale_only |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Is the query really this long?  It almost seems like it might be faster to query them both individually in this case

Comment: The length of the query should not matter (you can always create a view only once). On the other hand, no it does not need to be this long (the same where condition is applied 3x, it needs to be there only 2x)

Comment: I'm just trying to get the fastest query, not trying to create a view, etc. It looks like this query would actually be slower for mysql to process than doing two basic queries

Comment: @babonk, normally try to first get a working query (that you understand), then 2) improve the performance. Anyway, I updated my answer, it should perform no worse than two basic queries (that's what it essentially union all is - two queries processed independently and results of which are stuck together)